# Ruby on Rails webpage with Rails API for a mobile app (using the same data from a database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, mobile, html

I've been looking for a way to make one Web Application (with Ruby on Rails) and one API (also with Ruby on Rails) to serve a mobile application that i'm planning on develop (using React Native). The question is, what is the best way to make those two talk to each other?

To exemplify my need. I'll have one webpage and one mobile app that users can register and use. so i'm gonna need some authentication working on both sides. And also on the webpage i need to be able to manage the data that will display on those two.

I'm open to suggestion on a good way of accomplish that, kk. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a hybrid framework like phonegap (which has big advantages) you can use http://reactrb.org

This will let you code your entire single page app in ruby, with a rails backend.

For a list of hybrid frameworks see https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/hybrid-frameworks.md